# Automatically insert certain special characters at specific locations in a string using php codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-2

I have a text field to enter a code, and it structure is like `200-00-0000`.

When I enter the code in text field I have to generate the hyphen symbol(-) while typing the code at the specific locations as shown in the example code.

I'am using the PHP codeigniter.

Comment: You wants to generate phone number format or any license key ?

Comment: Where is your example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
<?php
    $data = '200000000';
    echo "".substr($data, 0, 3)."-".substr($data, 3, 3)."-".substr($data,6); // 200-000-0000
?>
```

check the [DEMO](https://eval.in/737200) here.

In case if you wants to create phone number format then you can use this as follows:

```
<?php
    $data = '2000000000';
    echo "(".substr($data, 0, 3).") ".substr($data, 3, 3)."-".substr($data,6); // (200) 000-0000
?>
```

[DEMO for phone number format](https://eval.in/737202)

Now; In case if you wants to go with some js code then you can use that as follows:

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.62/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input type='text' id='customtext' name='customtext' />
</body>
</html>
```

JS CODE:

```
$(window).load(function()
{
   var phones = [{ "mask": "###-###-####"}, { "mask": "(###) ###-##############"}];
    $('#customtext').inputmask({ 
        mask: phones, 
        greedy: false, 
        definitions: { '#': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1}} });
});
```

[JS DEMO LINK](https://jsbin.com/babufehesa/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks. But I have a text field as input field,while typing the code it should automatically insert the hyphen.Can you help me.

Comment: you have to use the jquery library for that http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/phone.html

Comment: I have updated my answer , Please check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was exactly what I need.